# gnuplot title variables separated by text

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to add text+variable+text+variable into the title of the plot in gnuplot batch file.

I have variables lines and last containing numbers(1 and 350) and the code Ive got  is:

```
set title sprintf("Secondary structure CA IX residues".first,"to".lines)
```

It prints: "Secondary structure CA IX1".

Can anyone help how to write this correctly, so that it will write  Secondary structure CA IX residues 1 to 350 with gaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use the `.` operator to concatenate your variables into strings:

   ```
   set title "Secondary structure CA IX residues " . first . " to " . lines
   ```

   I have added in spaces between the `"` and `.` for clarity, these will not be featured in the output. You are responsible for adding in the appropriate spaces in the string sections.
2. Use `sprintf` as it was intended:

   ```
   set title sprintf("Secondary structure CA IX residues %d to %d", first, lines)
   ```

   The first argument to `sprintf` is a format string, which should **not** contain any variables. Placeholders (such as `%d`) are used to indicate the positions that variables should be inserted. Subsequent arguments to the function are the variables to be inserted. As your two variables appear to be integers, `%d` is the appropriate format specifier to use.

Comment: thank you very much! :) also for explaining  the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you need spaces, insert them!

```
first = 1
lines = 350
set title sprintf("Secondary structure CA IX residues %d to %d", first, lines)
```